# Devise errors are displayed twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Using Devise for authorization I configured it to authorize by email or login.
Validatable driver deleted. I wrote validates in my user model.
Also I overwrite devise helper in app/helpers/devise_helper.rb:

```
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!
    return "" if resource.errors.empty?

    errors = Array.new

    resource.errors.each do |field, msg|
      errors.push(msg)
    end
    flash[:alert] = errors
  end
end
```

In view (devise/registrations/new.html.erb) I replace

```
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
```

to

```
<% devise_error_messages! %>
```

So, problem. 
When fields are empty (or else), flash errors are showing. Then I go to main page, and errors show again. It's appear only in registration interface. When authorization thats all right.
Please help.

**Updated.**

partial view (_block_errors.html.erb):

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <% if msg.class == Array %>
    <% msg.each do |message| %>
      <%= content_tag :p, message, :class => "#{name}" %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <%= content_tag :p, msg, :class => "#{name}" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In layout it's called like:

```
<%= render 'layouts/block_errors' %>
```

**Solved!**

In overloaded method devise_error_messages! need to replace string:

```
flash[:alert] = errors
```

to

```
flash.now[:alert] = errors
```

Hope it helps anybody :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you don't have `alert` displayed anywhere else in your app?

Should look something like this

```
<% if flash[:alert] %>
  <p id="notice"><%= flash[:alert] %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the problem by deleting `<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>` in my the index.html.erb file

Comment: This did it for me.