# Handle devise 401 gracefully during sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a very simple sign_in page for a devise user. Upon submitting incorrect data, the log shows a '401 Unauthorized' and redirects me back to the sign_in page. I couldn't figure out a way to show error messages to the user.

I looked at `devise::sessions_controller#create` which is as follows,

```
 # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

  def auth_options
    { :scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new" }
  end
```

The flow gets interrupted at `warden.authenticate` in case of a failed authentication and the user get redirected to the 'new' which is the sign_in page.

I just need to show the user a invalid_credentials tooltip/flash_message. So I did it by modifying `:recall => "#{controller_path}#handle_create_fail" (look at auth_options) which calls  handle_create_fails`  when authentication fails, inside which I setup the error messages.

I am not sure if I overlooked something that devise already provides.

How can I handle this better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'devise' stores error messages in rails 'flash', using `flash[:notice]` for success messages and `flash[:alert]` for problems.

Here's this from the [devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise):

> Remember that Devise uses flash messages to let users know if sign in
>   was successful or failed. Devise expects your application to call
>   "flash[:notice]" and "flash[:alert]" as appropriate.

This means that in your view file (or more generally in your application layout file) you should include something similar to these lines:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, flash[:error], :id => "flash_error") if flash[:error] %>
<%= content_tag(:div, flash[:notice], :id => "flash_notice") if flash[:notice] %>
<%= content_tag(:div, flash[:alert], :id => "flash_alert") if flash[:alert] %>
```

Here are some similar questions/answers:

[Rails - Devise - Error messages when signing in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635986/rails-devise-error-messages-when-signing-in)

[Devise errors are displayed twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404412/devise-errors-are-displayed-twice)

[devise - Customizing the User Edit Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101979/devise-customizing-the-user-edit-pages)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am understanding you correctly, but by simply placing 'alert' in your view (sign_in.html.erb), Devise will flash the error message.

```
<div class="alert">
  <%= alert %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to be able to do something similar, along the lines of form-specific error messaging like you might have on most Rails forms (as opposed to a layout-wide, global flash).

You can check out what I came up with in this Github gist: https://gist.github.com/3792471

Basically (notes below assume a devise scope of `:user`):

- Add/use a custom `FailureApp`, used by devise+warden, which simply adds a "scoped" `flash` "indicator".  That is, if devise+warden is exiting quickly due to a failed login and has, therefore, set the `flash.now[:alert]`, add `flash.now[:user] = [:alert]`
- Extend `FormBuilder` (actually, `SimpleForm::FormBuilder` in my gist, but should work with others) to add a `#flash` method, which checks for the scoped indicator(s). If found, the matches are extracted/deleted from the `FlashHash` and rendered. If not found (that is, `flash[:alert]` may or may not exist, but `flash[:user]` either does not exist or does not include `:alert`), do nothing so the flash remains available for the default use case.
- Add rendering to relevant views/layouts.

Note that the layout in my example gist does not have conditional logic around the layout-rendered flash messages. I did that just do I could test to see what does and does not show up under various circumstances.